# Javascript works in FF but not Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have (what I thought) was a pretty simple JS script in order to display elements based on the page ID.  Works fine in FF but not Chrome or IE

Every page on the site I am working with has the line:

```
<input id="actualPageId" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxx"></input>
```

(where 'xxxxxx' is a unique numeric value to that page only, something like '12345').

My code is basically:

```
<div id="divToHide1" style="display: none;">blah blah blah</div>

<div id="divToHide2" style="display: none;">blah blah blah</div>
......


<script>
var checker = document.getElementById('actualPageId').value;
if (checker == 'xxxxxxx' ) {
           document.getElementById('divToHide1').style= "display: inline";
   }

if (checker == 'xxxxxxx' ) {
           document.getElementById('divToHide2').style= "display: inline";
   }
.......

</script>
```

The idea being it determines which page it is based in the value in the actualPageID input tag, and then un-hides the correct div accordingly.  Works great in FF, not in any other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools in Chrome and IE to see if the code is producing any errors?

Comment: Can you elaborate what happens in Firefox? Does either `if` get satisfied (use an alert to check)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use display property directly. **Why complicate things?**

```
document.getElementById('divToHide2').style.display= "inline";
```

Comment: Huzzah!  Worked like a charm.